# css property not working for IE6

Tags: css

I have this :

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.56)), color-stop(100%,rgba(210,210,210,1)));
```

Its working for all browsers and for IE9 , but not working for IE6
Can someone tell me what to use else

Regards

Comment: webkit means (safari & chrome) so it won't work in IE, this should work in IE `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');`

Comment: Standard gradients only work in modern browsers and not IE.

Comment: read this post if you want them in firefox http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/11/css-gradients-firefox-36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IE's old filter rules, the rule you mentioned in the question has a vendor prefix which is targeting webkit (chrome, safari etc) browsers only. - there's a neat generator [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) which will help you out in making cross-platform gradients. IE6-9's rules look like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 *
```

Answer (score 0):

The webkit prefix only works in Webkit browsers, which are Chrome, Safari, and Android and iPhone. For example, you'd need to use -moz for Firefox, and -o for Opera.

IE6 doesn't have any gradient support at all, so you'll need to use an image instead, or drop IE6 support, which is probably a good choice; not many users are still on IE6. (Unless this is meant for use specifically in for example governments, they're often stuck.)

Comment: IE6-9 do support gradients, but through filter: declarations

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer gradient filter doesn't support color-stop, gradient angle, and radial gradient. That means you can only specify either horizontal or vertical linear gradient with 2 colors: StartColorStr and EndColorStr.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 and lower aren't the only browsers that don't support gradients, so using filters won't catch all browsers.

Another approach is [to use Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to feature detect support and use a fallback image or solid colour.

For example:

```
#box {
// Normal gradient syntax
}

.no-cssgradients #box {
// Fallback image
}
```